# disabled not working in angular2 input

Tags: user-input, angular2-forms

Hi My diable is not working in Angular2. though the condition is false but the input box is disabled.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="{{'LblUserProvidedOdometerValueInKmr' | translate }}" [(ngModel)]="model.userProvidedOdometerValueInKm"          name="userProvidedOdometerValueInKm" 
    maxlength="6" 
    [disabled]="isEditMode && !(authService.GetHighestRoleLevel() <= roleLevel.Instance)">
```

values are isEditMode = true,authService.GetHighestRoleLevel() =3 and roleLevel.Instance=2. Input field should not be disabled. Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to right a function for disabling like [disabled] = "check()"
and right you logic inside the check function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[disabled]="(isEditMode) && !(authService.GetHighestRoleLevel() <= roleLevel.Instance)"
```

I have changed my code to this and it is resolved.